# remaining words of string in php

Tags: php, string, words

I have a piece of code that shows the first 20 words on my webpage.

```
$arrtext = explode( ' ', stripslashes( str_replace('\n',chr(10),str_replace('\r',chr(13),$row['text']))), $config['length_story'] + 1);

$arrtext[ $config['length_story'] ] = '';

$row['headtext'] = trim(implode( ' ', $arrtext)) . '...';
```

This works fine but I want to display the remaing text too without repeating the first 20 words how can I do this?

Comment: What's all that `str_replace`-ing about?

Comment: Quite complicated, this.

Comment: some problems with certain chrs that displayed wrong on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without rewriting anything, just save the content of

```
$arrtext[ $config['length_story'] ] = '';
```

before overwriting it. it already contains the remaining text

```
$remaining = $arrtext[ $config['length_story'] ];
$arrtext[ $config['length_story'] ] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd do something like this:

```
$story = $row['text']; // apply whatever here, `stripslashes`, `sre_replace`...
preg_match("/^((?:\S+\s+){20})(.*)$/",$story,$match);
if( $match)
    $result = Array($match[1],$match[2]);
else
    $result = Array($story,"");
```

Now `$result` contains two elements: The first elements is the first 20 words of the story, the second is everything after.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Looks like it should be working but I went with the second solution. Less re-writing of the original code.